# Numpy matrix functions with Numba

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba

I am new to Python programming.
 I have the following Python 3.6 code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def genarray(rows, cols):
    """return a new matrix"""
    return np.zeros([rows, cols], float)
L1 = 5
C1 = 5
B = genarray(L1, C1)
print(type(B))
```

When I compile I obtain the following error:

```
TypingError: >Invalid usage of Function(<built-in function zeros>) with parameters (list(int64), Function(<class 'float'>))

 * parameterized
```

I tried with `np.float, np.float64` and I obtain errors. The code compiles OK without the `nopython=true` option.

How solve the error with the matrices? Because with vector the code compiles OK
with `nopython=true` option.

Comment: If you are new to Python (and I assume `numpy`) why are you playing with `numba`?  That's an advanced tool meant to speed up iterative `numpy` calculations.  Can you write that function without `numba`?  Is it too slow?

Answer (score 3):

I second the concern that worrying about numba at this point may not be the most productive path. That said, you can achieve your goal by passing a tuple and not a list to `np.zeros` and using `np.float64`:

```
>>> @jit(nopython=True)
... def genarray(rows, cols):
...     """return a new matrix"""
...     return np.zeros((rows, cols), np.float64)
... 
>>> L1 = 5
>>> C1 = 5
>>> B = genarray(L1, C1)
>>> print(type(B))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> B
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

If this seems pretty finicky, you're right: but that's the tradeoff with using numba at the moment.